# Pandas apply function isn't working and without any error

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following function for removing any special character:

```
def cleanText(text):
   html_tags = re.compile('<*?>|&([a-z0-9]+|#[0-9]{1,6}|#x[0-9a-f]{1,6}|);')
   text = re.sub(html_tags, '', text)
   table = str.maketrans(' ',' ', string.punctuation)
   stripped = str.lower(text.translate(table).strip())
   return stripped
```

and dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5],'text':["sh4@$F","gj8(#f","'w'e`","gfd&&8)+","&#*"]})
```

I want to clean the `text` column of any punctuations so according to online guides I've found:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: cleanText(x) if x.name == 'text' else x, axis = 1)
```

but it seems like the function doesn't work on the dataframe (When i test it on just random string it works). I've checked my if I used the 'apply` function correctly and according to the several guides I found this is how it supposed to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you wanted:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(cleanText)
```

(if you want just one column "cleaned", apply the function to this column only).

Comment: Yes it works.. Strange for some reason the first time I tried it the output of all of the rows were the same (as the first row). Thanks!!